# Are universities strategic about when they release grad school admissions results?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I recently went through the process of applying to graduate school (in mathematics, in the US).

Of course, decisions come out at very different times. For example, two of the departments I applied to had applications due on the same day, were of similar size and prestige, and likely received a similar number of applications, whereas I (and most other applicants) heard from one in the first week of January, and the other in the middle of February.

I assumed graduate schools simply release decisions as soon as they can / as soon as their committee can come to a decision, and because administration is difficult, this causes huge variance between when departments are able to release results. However, **do some graduate schools actively decide to release results earlier or later than others in order to strategize?**

- One potential reason to try and release decisions as early as possible is so that students become invested in the school as early as possible and have more time to decide to go visit, reach out to professors, etc.
- One potential reason to release decisions later would be if a lower-ranked department wanted to give some time for some of the applicants to withdraw their applications after getting into other places, so they know who's actually invested and might actually come. It must be very frustrating to admit the best X% of your applicants only to have most of them decline the offer soon afterwards because they got into a school they see as more prestigious.

Comment: Are you familiar with https://cgsnet.org/resources/for-current-prospective-graduate-students/april-15-resolution/ ? This agreement limits the potential games for schools to play and most US schools participate.